# Why encrypt and decrypt binary data to Base64

Tags: node.js, react-native, encryption, react-redux

I'm on my journey to build my first react-native app. I have seen a few videos on how to decrypt and encrypt binary data to base64 using aes-crypto, but still having some trouble understanding why we do it. So before we put binary data back to the database, if we encrypt it and when we pull it out, we decrypt it, does that affect performance or is there any reason behind it?

I know it's a newbie question, but I really want to understand the reason why we do it so if anyone could give me any guidance, I will much appreciate it.

Cheers

Comment: The encoding or decoding is done for transport, storage or viewing purpose. One example: after encryption you have a lot of "bytes" that are not viewable- think of x00 (hex). Base64 enables a lossless conversion between binary data and a string version.

Comment: Aaa ok, I got it now. That helps! Legend!

Comment: @minhpham: I somehow feel current answers miss the aes part of your question. Could you clarify whether you use plain base64 or encrypt with aes? The two, base64 and aes are very different.

Comment: @WiktorZychla The reason I put out this question because I watched the following videos: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vj723NlrIQc. And he said that by using native encrypt/decrypt (In this case, is the library which he mentioned: https://github.com/craftzdog/react-native-aes-gcm-crypto), it made his app faster. I assume as Michael and jfriend explained, maybe the database which he used doesn't accept binary so he has to use based64 encoding, and as react-native use javascript runtime, the encrypt/decrypt process take longer to process. Hence, increase the performance using native en/decrypt

Comment: @minhpham: why encrypt at all? Plain base64 should be faster than aes.

Comment: @WiktorZychla That's my question as well. In my understanding, he's trying to use native encode/decode instead of javascript runtime encode/decode. The thing I don't quite understand is he used it for binary data processing.

Comment: @minhpham: I don't understand this too. JavaScript has built-in buffer to base 64 encoding which should be way faster than aes. As long as you don't need encryption, I believe you don't need aes and this particular package. Stick with JavaScript conversion. I was under impression that this is your primary concern, why aes package is used.

Comment: Alright. That answered my question. Thanks Wiktor

Answer (score 1):

Base64 encoding is used when either a transport or storage mechanism does not accept binary data, but the data you want to send or store may have binary components to it.  In your case, you encrypt something and get a binary result.  You then base64 encode it to convert it that binary to a "text" or "string" representation that can still reproduce the actual binary with decoding, but describes that binary in a text form (it uses more bytes to do so).  It can then later losslessly be converted back to the original binary by decoding the base64.

For example, if you were storing in a database, you would not need to base64 encode it if the field type you were putting it in in the database accepted binary data, but if it didn't accept binary data, then you could base64 encode it to convert it to something that was safe to store in the database (a string).

FYI, Base64 is a coding scheme where you have 64 different codes you can use.  Those 64 codes are A-Z, a-z, 0-9 and + /.  That's 26 + 26 + 10 + 2 = 64.  You can see the codes [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).  The `=` character can also be used for padding to make the last block of characters a set of four Base64 characters.  So, technically 65 different characters can be used, though the `=` is just an empty placeholder and not part of the actual encoded data.  Padding is not necessary for accurate decoding, but is still used in some circumstances.

The 64 characters are 2^6 so this is essentially 6-bit encoding.  Three 8-bit values are put into four 6-bit values where each 6-bit values is represented by a different one of the 64 different characters.  So, blocks of four Base64 encoded characters decode to three 8-bit values.

This is not a whole lot different than the text-based hexadecimal or text-based binary representation.  In hexadecimal, each 8-bit original value is represented by two 4-bit characters (16 different characters) where something like 127 is `7F`.  In text-based binary, each byte of data is represented by 8 zeroes and ones and 127 would be `01111111`.  Base64 is the same, but it uses a 64 character set instead of the smaller sets of hexadecimal (16) or binary (2).

Comment: What a great answer! Thanks, jfriend, it makes a lot of sense now.